# In Rails 5.2, using Carrierwave gem how can I use the default gem when the file no longer exists on disk?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, actioncontroller

I'm using Carrierwave gem on Rails 5.2.2.1. I have it setup with a default url to an image when one doesn't exist in the database for that record.  But how can I have it also show up if I have an image in the database for the record, but that file doesn't exist on the disk?

Currently, I get the following error:

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]
>   "/uploads/player/314c38a9-6567-4faa-bfda-9e7a75cbaed4.jpeg")

Is there a way to rescue and present the default url I've specified in the Uploader file?

Comment: Something seems strange here since you're getting a `RoutingError` and not an actual 404. Do you have a route setup to handle `GET /uploads/player/*` somehow?

This also seems like a bit of a data integrity problem. If the files don't exist on disk, I'd remove them from the database. Then your application code can recognise that there is no file for that record.

Comment: @mroach, I don't seem to have that route setup anywhere.  And I agree it is a bit of a data integrity problem as the file no longer exists on the disk and should be removed. But was still trying to figure out if there was a way to do it short of writing a script that would run and check if files were on the disk ever so often

Comment: The problem seems to be that your database records have file paths that aren't handled at all. For example, I would expect the `/uploads/player/*` route to be handled by static file serving, but Rails is trying to process this like a normal route. So as long as your database generates bad paths, you're going to have routing errors. The solution by @ilyaostov is the way to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a default image, you can set method in your model like this

```
def image
  File.file?(file.path) ? file.url : default_image_url #and you need to define this default url
end
```

Or you can handle 404 on an image as @mroach mentioned in your routes

Comment: Is there a better way of incorporating this into the Uploader file that I've created with Carrierwave so that I don't have yet another method for the image to replace?  For instance can I override the .url method for the uploader to handle this?

Comment: You need to have models which use your uploader. There you can set this method. It is bad practice to override the URL method. You can look at the source code of this method in the Carrierwave repository and look at what you can destroy by this)